# I have an error: it is not abstract and does not override the abstract method actionPerformed

Tags: java, eventos

Este es mi código:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class AreaAndfield extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JTextField field1;
private JButton boton1;
private JTextArea area1;
private JScrollPane panel1;

String text = "";

public AreaAndfield(){
    
    setLayout(null);
    
    field1 = new JTextField();
    field1.setBounds(10,10,150,40);
    add(field1);
    
    boton1 = new JButton("AGREGAR");
    boton1.setBounds(170,10,200,40);
    add(boton1);
    boton1.addActionListener(this);
    
    area1 = new JTextArea();
    panel1 = new JScrollPane(area1);
    panel1.setBounds(10,60,300,300);
    add(panel1);
}

public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e){
    
    if(e.getSource() == boton1){
        
        text += field1.getText();
        area1.setText(text);
        field1.setText("");
        
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    
    AreaAndfield interfaz1 = new AreaAndfield();
    interfaz1.setBounds(0,0,400,420);
    interfaz1.setVisible(true);
    interfaz1.setResizable(true);
    interfaz1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

}

A la hora de ejecutar este código, tengo un error el cual dice: **AreaAndfield.java:4: error: AreaAndfield is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener**, y no se que es lo que sucede, e revisado el código varias veces y no noto ningún error, incluso lo e comparado con otro código, y no se exactamente en que falla el código, el error solo aparece, lo compare con el siguiente codigo:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class AreaAndfield extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

 private JTextField textfield1;
 private JScrollPane scrollpane1;
 private JTextArea textarea1;
 private JButton boton1;

 String texto = "";

 public AreaAndfield(){
  setLayout(null);
  textfield1 = new JTextField();
  textfield1.setBounds(10,10,200,30);
  add(textfield1);

  boton1 = new JButton("Agregar");
  boton1.setBounds(250,10,100,30);
  add(boton1);
  boton1.addActionListener(this);

  textarea1 = new JTextArea();
  scrollpane1 = new JScrollPane(textarea1);
  scrollpane1.setBounds(10,50,400,300);
  add(scrollpane1);
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  if(e.getSource() == boton1){
    texto += textfield1.getText() + "\n";
    textarea1.setText(texto);
    textfield1.setText("");
  }
 }

 public static void main(String args[]){
  AreaAndfield interfaz1 = new AreaAndfield();
  interfaz1.setBounds(0,0,540,400);
  interfaz1.setVisible(true);
  interfaz1.setResizable(false);
  interfaz1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 }
}
```

La única diferencia que veo es el identado, pero aun así el primero falla y el otro no,**(Por si acaso, el segundo código no es mío, es uno al que le hice unos cambios probando a ver por que fallaba el mío, pero no encontré nada)**, agradecería mucho que me digan por que esta fallando mi código y como podría arreglarlo, es que si no puedo arreglarlo no podre colocar eventos, también agradecería que probaran el primer código y me digan si a ustedes le falla, para asi saber si solo es a mi, se los agradezco.

Comment: El código que tu tienes es el primero verdad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer código que pasaste tiene un error, este es en tu método llamado `actionPerfomed` este no es implementado por la interfaz `ActionListener` este es un simple método como cualquier otro, el error esta en que te equivocaste al escribirlo, el nombre real es `actionPerformed` te falto una r.

Y cuando escribas este método implementado por la interfaz acordate de escribir @Override.

Al copiar tu código el IDE me pidió que implemente el método, y al revisar este ya lo habías escrito, entonces me di cuenta que no lo estabas implementando y que te hacías equivocado en el nombre.

Creo que este es el problema, hay que decir que a mi no me salto ningún error en ninguno de los código que pasaste, por lo que le di un par de vueltas, todos se ejecutaban bien, pero si tuve que implementar el método.